# Game programming best practice, movement in or outside class?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am making my first game in C++ (SFML 2.0) right now and I'm trying to do it as clean as possible. After some fiddling around with code I am going to convert it to object orientated code, but movement has got me thinking.

I am thinking of passing the `sf::Event` to the update function to read the button presses and do movement inside the class. But I am not sure is that is a smart move to make. Code is going to be clean, but I remember reading somewhere that stuff like button presses should not be done inside a class. The thing is that I don't have a clue why and if it's even true.

Is there someone that can give me some tips on this?

Comment: You'll need to explain much better than that.  There are so many different design patterns that your question is unanswerable here.  If I say "do this" I will get spammed with people saying that is wrong.  Give us some objects, tell us more, maybe a little code so we can help you in your specific situation.

Comment: You can safely dispose of any *X should not be done inside a class* advice.  Classes (and OOP in general) provide a particular way for you to organize your logic and allow the compiler to enforce some of your own organizational rules.  That in itself is not a Bad Thing.

Comment: @CharlesW Yeah I tried putting some code in, but I'm in the middle of converting it to OOP code, so it's a huge mess.

Comment: I was trying to make example also @Gideon, then I kinda gave up the ghost on that.  Figured- explain better is better answer, we can help him/her/it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit broad, but here is a tip that I think people will be hard-pressed to disagree with.  Separate input devices(keyboard, mouse, etc...) from actions.  Your game objects should not respond to, nor know anything about, the Left key on the keyboard.  Instead, they should respond, for example, to a "Go Left" command.  In separate code (perhaps an ObjectController class), you bind the Left key to the "Go Left" command.  This makes controls much more configurable, because you can easily bind the `A` key, or the left joystick button instead. Or you can switch the object from player controlled to computer controlled by plugging in an AI that issues the "Go Left" command.

Comment: So it is 'best' to not let the object decide where to go, but just make functions to let it move?

Comment: @Gideon: You see the advantage, do you not?

Comment: Not at the moment, but I got something working right now. Hopefully I will notice the awesomeness in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes as Benjamin Lindley said, the smartest choice is to have the inputs stored in a container (either make an input queue, list or a boolean map for keys) and then in your game logic, depending on the inputs, call your objects update methods.
A short SFML exemple:

```
  sf::Clock timer;
  sf::Event Event;
  bool isRunning = true;
  while (isRunning)
    {
      Window.clear(sf::Color(255, 255, 255));
      while (Window.pollEvent(Event))
      {
          switch(Event.type)
            {
             case sf::Event::Closed:
             isRunning = false;
             break;

            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                    if (Event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up)
                    keys[WK] = true;
                        [...]

                case sf::Event::KeyReleased:
                    if (Event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up)
                    keys[WK] = false;
                        [...]
                }
          }
      if (keys[WK])
          MyCharacter.move(0, -100 * timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds());
      Window.draw(MyCharacter);

      Window.display();
      timer.restart();
    }
```

This is an exemple of how i deal with the inputs in a game i made. "keys" is a boolean array and i set the different keys to true or false depending on if they're pressed or not. Then after the event polling and keys update is done, i have my game logic (here i removed all but one line to simplify the exemple). Remember to use the timer to keep a constant gameplay.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll compare it to my code and see if I can improve anything, thanks for the code!